# Looking for a movie about a man in cryostasis trying to escape

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie about a man who is dead and put in cryostasis (I think we only know that at the end when he "wakes up" thanks to new technology)

During the movie, he always relives the same time of his life, which restarts every time he dies (I think he died of overdose once in his bathroom the first time, and he could see everyone mourning him before coming back).

He may have met with the cryostasis company while being in his "dream" and be afraid / sceptical of their methods (keep in mind he didn't know he was already dead and under cryostasis )

I'm pretty sure he died more than once due to suicide (overdose, maybe veins being cut, maybe due to binge drinking), which he does either because he's sick (that would explain why he saw a cryostasis company) or because he had problems with his girlfriend.

The only way he has to come out of the loop is to jump off of a high building, but he has vertigo. I think there's someone from the real word that advise him or try to stop him from doing escaping.

I think I've seen this movie somewhere around 2010 but it was probably older (not sure, the TV / channel could have make me think that). I'd say around 1990 - 2010 for the image quality & phone size.

The characters were white, the movie was (probably) in an American city.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sounds almost like the 2001 Tom Cruise film [*Vanilla Sky*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0259711/). Which is about Cruise's character living a happy life which he comes to realise is not what it seems. He has entered an artificial life after a car crash in which he was badly disfigured ultimately lead to him committing suicide in the real world and entering the fake world.

It fits the cryostasis company (called Life Extension). Cruise's character David "realizes that he is now living in the Lucid Dream". He doesn't constantly re-live the same day but he does get it 'reset' with key characters replaced in the dream "one night he goes to bed with Sofia and wakes up to find himself with Julianna, who insists she really is Sofia"

The reason he enters the dream in the first place was suicide:

> But David, suffering constant pain and depression following his disfigurement, committed suicide.

Ultimately;

> In the end, technical support reveals an upgrade to the software which allows David to either be reinserted into the lucid dream with no memory of the nightmare portion or to be awakened in the present time (which is 150 years after he was frozen) and live in the real world with a restored body. David chooses to be awakened in this future present realizing that everyone he ever knew will be long dead and his wealth will be worth far less. After one last lucid-dream rooftop exchange with Sofia in which she vows to "find you again" he leaps off the skyscraper.

Quotes taken from the [film's synopsis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0259711/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl#synopsis)

Does the trailer ring any bells?

Comment: JFYI, Vanilla Sky is a Hollywood remake of the Spanish movie [Abre los ojos (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0125659/) (Open Your Eyes). IMHO, original is better than the remake.

Comment: Both starring Penélope Cruz as Sofia, that's a nice little callback to the original.

Comment: "original is better than the remake" - are there *any* counter examples to that?

Comment: @MartinBonner Heat, 12 Monkeys, Scarface, True Grit, The Departed, The Thing (the first remake :p). Disclaimer: taken from the list here: http://screenrant.com/remakes-better-than-original/. And while I did not watched the originals and I cannot judge them, I do consider the remakes very very good.